# jquery does not get expected height from element populated with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a div that is initially empty and with display set to none.

Then, with user selection, an ajax call is activated and loads the content.

Due to a somewhat fancy positioning of the div's I have to force the height so that is gets displayed correctly.

I set up a function to calculate the height of the parent div after ajax, but it is giving me an unexpected result, which has nothing to do with the actual height of the division.

At the initial page load, the calculation occurs correctly, but the it goes bad with the ajax call.

It is when it calculated the height of the div 'main' within the ajax call that it somehow get a much higher figure then what the reality is.

Thanks for your assistance.

A summarized html:

```
<div class="content_wrapall">
     <div id="main">
          <div id="slide1">some content ....</div
          <div id="alltabs"></div> // initially set to display:none
     </div>

     <div id="info">some content...</div>

     <div id="pub"> some content... </div>
</div>
```

This is the ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hook10").change(function () {
        var str = $(".hook10").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "comp_all_ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: str,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#alltabs").html(data);
                $('#' + 'alltabs').css({
                    "display": "inline"
                });
                content_height();

            },
            complete: function () {
                $("#tabs, #tabs10").tabs();

                $(function () {
                    $(".tool").click(calltip);
                });

            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is the function to adjust the height. It is working fine at the initial page load.

```
function content_height() {
    if (wid > 760) {
        var c_height = [];
        c_height.push($('#pub').outerHeight());
        c_height.push($('#main').outerHeight());
        c_height.push($('#info').outerHeight());
        var max_height = Math.max.apply(Math, c_height);
        $('.content_wrapall').height(max_height);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    content_height();
});
```

Comment: In the meantime I was reviewing my 'fancy' positioning and decided to compromise a bit to get something still fancy but that would have a height. So I accomplished that and I am leaving this issue aside. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a div that is initially empty and with display set to none.

`height()` and `width()` will only return the correct results if the element is visible, so if they have `display: none` when you call those functions, the result will be wrong (usually 0).

Comment: Thanks UweB. If you look at the ajax call, in 'success',  I set the display back to 'normal' before calling the function to calculate the height. I tried specifically also setting it to 'inline', but the issue remains.